# Django feature (run custom method from admin) missing: why, security?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-admin, dry

A feature I have been missing several times is a *simple* way to create a button in the admin-change-view, which would trigger some custom method of the model.

I have searched thoroughly, I hope^^, so I'm pretty sure it's not available to do this easily.
I know about admin-actions, but only for the list view (and they require to specially prepare the methods). There is also the possibility to provide a custom `ModelForm`, and maybe more... but why nothing easy!?

Something like:

```
class MyAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    method_buttons = [{
        'method': 'my_custom_method', 
        'display_name': 'Click Me!', 
        'name': 'foo_button', 
    }, ]

    fieldsets = (('Bar Fieldset', {'fields': (..., 'foo_button')}),)
```

I think it really would be a common use-case!

Should I file a feature request/try to write this feature myself? Or is there a reason why this shouldn't be implemented?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, it works, thank you. I would not really call it easy, though, especially for new users (I have been writing a page for some months now, which is still new, but not quite). Also, I cannot add the button to a fieldset this way, can I? So I'm still thinking some feature would give benefit here

Comment: yes, I know ;) I have not been here for some days, sorry; and I had upvoted the answer at once, but wanted to think it over before accepting; after all, my question was not "how can I accomplish it" but "is it possible/desirable to add such a feature"

Comment: no worries. Thanks for the upvoate

Answer (score 2):

There is actually quite a well defined way of getting this sort of thing done. The first thing is to [override the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to add whatever button that you want. It's usually a matter of copying the template from your django installations `contrib/admin/templates/` and adding a bit of HTML.

But you are still left with the problem of what to do when that button is clicked. That's done by overriding the [get_urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) method. This example is adapted form that.

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^my_view/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view)),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls

def my_view(self, request):
    # ...
    if request.POST.get('SOMETHING YOU ADD'):
        model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('pk')
        model.do_something();

    context = dict(
       # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
       self.admin_site.each_context(request),
       # Anything else you want in the context...
       key=value,
    )
    return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```

You can even use regular django forms in your custom view to make things neater.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the idea for a "hack" recently; but only after searching and thinking for a long time, so this doesn't make the need for the feature obsolete.

Create a boolean-field and manipulate the `save()` (or maybe the admin-save-method would be cleaner) so that it performs the desired action if the field is checked (and resets the field).

This is pretty easy, but probably an abuse of the functionality in some sense, isn't it?